# React-Native; App stuck on loading screen after update to react navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Recently I've updated my app to `React Navigation V5`.
However, I got a problem, my app is stuck on the Splash Screen of the app.
The code seems to compile, and I get no error back.

I suspected it could be the old `createSwitchNavigator` method which doesn't exist anymore and I did it wrong, however, if I put a console log at the beginning of the component, nothing happens, I get no log back, even if I delete all the code, no error and the app is still stuck there. All I get in the console is:

```
Running application appname ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 31;
})
infoLog.js:16 Running "appname" with {"rootTag":31,"initialProps":{}}
RCTLog.js:47 Manifest does not exist - creating a new one.

(null)
```

But they are no errors, only RCTLogs.
Any ideeas about any debugging techniques or any thread that could help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: update your navigation stack and remove switch navigator. Switch navigator is not present in the navigation v5

Comment: I've changed my switch to the new syntax, and, yeah, i said i updated it

Comment: Can you add the code app entrypoint -> navigator -> initial screen?